# If $ab+bc+ca=0$ then the value of $1/(a^2-bc)+1/(b^2-ac)+1/(c^2-ab)$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $ab+bc+ca=0$

then the value of

$1/(a^2-bc)+1/(b^2-ac)+1/(c^2-ab)$ is...

Comment: (a+b+c)^3 formula ahh

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{1}{a^2+ab+ca}+\frac{1}{b^2+ab+bc}+\frac{1}{c^2+ca+bc}$$
$$=\frac{1}{a(a+b+c)}+\frac{1}{b(a+b+c)}+\frac{1}{c(a+b+c)}=\frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc(a+b+c)}=0.$$

Comment: nicely elegant :)

Comment: @Surb: Thanks:)

Comment: no.how 1/(a2-bc)=1/a^2+ab+ca explain @mathlove

Comment: @jyothika: Because $ab+bc+ca=0\Rightarrow -bc=ab+ca$.

Comment: okay thank you @mathlove

Comment: @jyothika: You are welcome.

Comment: @mathlove this answer does not hold even if one of them is zero.

Comment: I need to know  how to edit the question for sin,cos,tan,theta,pi ,summation etc when posting question

Comment: @DSinghvi: If $a=0$, we have $bc=0$. This leads $a^2-bc=0$, which is a contradiction. So, we have $abc\not =0$.

Comment: @jyothika: The following page may be helpful : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @mathlove Which contradiction ? THe domain of these variables?

Comment: @DSinghvi: I suppose $a^2-bc\not =0,b^2-ca\not =0,c^2-ba\not =0$ because the question asks the value of $1/(a^2-bc)+1/(b^2-ca)+1/(c^2-ab)$.

Answer (score -1):

$ab+bc+ca=0$

$a(b+c)= -bc$

$b+c= -bc/a$

Adding both side $a$ then $b+c+a=a-bc/a$

$a(a+b+c)= a^2-bc$

$1/(a^2-bc)= 1/a(a+b+c)$

Similarly $1/(b^2-ca) = 1/b(a+b+c)$

and $1/(c^2-ab) = 1/c(a+b+c)$.

By adding all eqution we get

$1/a(a+b+c)+ 1/b(a+b+c)+ 1/c(a+b+c)$